# NSString: Regular Expression for blabla.DDD+DDDD where D is digit

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nsstring

I need a regular expression to check if a string has this pattern:

[some random characters].DDD+DDDD

it can start with random characters, but it ends with a dot . then three digits, then a plus sign followed by four digits. How can I construct the regular expression and check if a NSString has this pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regex is `^[^.]*\.[0-9]{3}\+[0-9]{4}$`

Both of the other answers forgot to escape certain characters.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you are looking for.

```
NSString *regex = @"(^[^.]*\.[0-9]{3}\+[0-9]{4}$)";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPRedicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
if ([pred evaluateWithObject:mystring])
{
  //do something
}
```

There are many good Regex Generators to test your regular expressions.
E.x.: http://rubular.com

Comment: Closer!  But [^.]*. means "Any characters but a period, followed by any character"  It needs to be [^.]*\.

Answer (score -1):

The expression ^[^.]*\.[0-9]{3}\+[0-9]{4}$ should do it.

The ^ means start of string
[^.]*\. means zero or more non-period characters followed by a period
[0-9]{3} means 3 digits (0-9)
\+ means a plus
[0-9]{4} means 4 digits
The $ means end of string

Comment: Close, but not correct.  You need to escape the middle + because it is a regex key character.  So is the period after *. (Any character will work in that position).  It also needs to be escaped

Comment: I could have sworn I escaped the +. Fixed. Turns out I did but I needed to enter two in the post so one would appear. Live and learn.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain so everyone can learn what the issue is?

Comment: Really? Two down votes when my answer is correct and was first. The accepted and upvoted answers are the same as my answer. Plus my answer actually explains what the regex means. Come on people. If you are going to down vote something like this, have a good reason.

Comment: I upvoted your answer to counteract that since, as you said, it is correct and even has an explanation :).  Unfortunately I think you are the victim of the "omg something is downvoted I need to downvote it too" mob mentality.